# Need to transfer files(No SCP) from Linux to IBM-AIX

Tags: linux, ftp, aix, file-transfer, scp

I need to transfer a tar.gz file from RHEL5 to IBM AIX... The IBM AIX does not have scp and I dont think, I could install, as I am just using the system for temporary purposes. Is there an alternative for that.. In most of the forums I read, they talk about ftp, but I cannot ftp from the AIX server to Linux system either... Do I need to have some kinda thing running on my linux system for the AIX server to ftp? I am ftping the IPADDR, like ftp . If there are any other alternative please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: rsync - http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/date.html

Comment: Do you connect remotely to the IBM AIX machine? If yes, how? If you are physically moving in from of it, just move also a physical storage (e.g. an USB key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer files with netcat. It usually is present on most nix like systems.

On the system with file you need to execute

```
cat /path/to/file | nc -l -p 7878
```

On the receiver:

```
nc remotehost -p 7878 > received_file
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to ftp into the Linux server, you need an FTP server running on it.

You can also try transferring over HTTP if you have a HTTP client on IBM AIX. You will have to run a HTTP server on Linux and serve the file you want to download.

Or just over netcat.

Bear in mind that all these ways (unlike rsync) can't guarantee file integrity, so I suggest to check it manually after you succeed to transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an NFS mount between the two.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer and explain how the OP would go about doing that, what the benefits are, et cetera?

Comment: ^Actually I created the NFS mount and it worked..... Thanks!!!

Comment: Again, it would be really helpful if you could explain how to do that.

Comment: @awojo The reason we are asking for you to expand on the answer is because it will help others who come to this site and don't know how to do that specifically, sending them to other sites for "simple" info